# Ler string de uma coluna e retornar valores em outra no vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Olá,

Não entendo muito de VBA e queria saber se alguém poderia me ajudar.

Gostaria de saber como posso pegar uma string de uma coluna(ex: A), lê o dado dela e retornar em uma nova coluna. Nessa coluna nova seria retornado "verdadeiro" se fosse "A", "falso" se fosse diferente de "A".

E esse código iria ler todas as linhas dessa coluna com a string.

Alguém tem ideia de como faço isso ?

Já Procurei e não consigo achar nada parecido com isso.

O código que eu fiz para testar essa ideia foi esse(ele traz como se todas as linhas fossem diferentes de A):

```
Private Sub cmdaon_Click()


Dim counter As Integer
Dim rng1 As Range

Set rng1 = destSheet1.Range("A:L")

Ln = 2

Do While rng1.Cells(Ln, 1).Value <> ""

   If Cells(Ln, 9).Value = "A" Then

         Cells(Ln, 13).Select
         Cells(Ln, 13).Value = "Verdadeiro"
   Else

      Cells(Ln, 13).Value = "Falso"

    End If


    Ln = Ln + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Macro1()
'Dados na coluna A e resultado na coluna E (offset 0,4)
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("A1:A8")
Dim dados As Range


For Each dados In rng1
    If dados.Value = "A" Then
        dados.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Verdadeiros"
    Else: dados.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Falso"
    End If
Next
End Sub
```